# Single Sign On Service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, single-sign-on

I have a web application hosted outside bluemix. However, I would like to use the Single Sign on service available on bluemix for authentication. Is that possible. What are the steps involved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a scenario question and not appropriate for Stack Overflow. See the Stack Overflow FAQ called How do I ask a good question? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It would be better if you asked it on dW Answers (https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the Single Sign On Service within Bluemix is only designed to work with Bluemix hosted Node.js and JAVA(Liberty) applications.  It will not work with applications outside of Bluemix